# Best way to send XML results from a curl

Tags: jenkins, groovy, slack

we have a Jenkins pipeline that sends a sh 'curl' request to a an api/application to runs specific tests for us, and we fail/pass the build depending on the results.

What I want to do: is to parse the information we get back from the curl (XML document) and send these notifications via Slack.

What I've done so far is exactly that, parse the XML document, able to print the results locally, but when I try to send this result to slack I get a error: I am assuming this is because I saved my results as an Array, and when I am trying to send the information to slack its unable to reference the variable.

My question is: How should we send XML results to Slack and how can we properly parse the XML file and send it to slack?

My code snippet:

```
            List <String> someString = new ArrayList<String>()
            parsed = new XmlSlurper().parse("${workspace}/tmp/TESTS-results.xml")


            parsed.testsuite.testcase.each { device ->
            someString.add(device.@name)
            someString.add(device.@time)
            someString.add(device)
            println deviceArr
            println deviceArr.getClass()
            }      
                parsed= XmlUtil.serialize(parsed)
                return deviceArr
            }
```

```
    in field groovy.lang.GString.values
    in object org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl@40198fcc
    in field groovy.lang.Closure.delegate
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@4a4ae500
    in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.closures
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@5dd0e25c
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@5dd0e25c
Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: groovy.util.slurpersupport.Attributes
```

Comment: first problem in your code that parsed xml could not be serialized. read about `@NonCPS`.

Comment: If you can, your best alternative will be to send JSON/YAML instead of XML. Then you'll be able to use the `readJSON`/`readYaml` steps.